# Pivot on duplicate column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

The query below is doing what I want, except a given `accessruleId` could have more than one `businessArea`. So, the current query is just grabbing the max one instead of all of them.

I get `businessArea` column to list all of the values perhaps comma delimited like the screenshot below.
I am using SQL Server 2016.

```
AccessRuleId    EffectiveDate   TermDate    CreatedByUser   CreateDateTime  LastUpdatedUser LastUpdatedDateTime
       1          2019-12-13    2020-01-22  User1         2019-12-11    User2   2019-12-12 

RuleFieldId FieldName
1           BusinessArea
2           ProviderTaxId
3           VendorName

RuleOperationId AccessRuleId    Fieldid Value
1                     1             1   ABC
2                     1             2   1234537890
3                     1             3   Vendor1
30                    1             4   XYZ 

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ar.AccessRuleId
        ,ar.EffectiveDate
        ,ar.TermDate
        ,ar.CreatedByUser
        ,ar.LastUpdatedUser
        ,rf.FieldName
        ,ro.Value
    FROM AccessRule.AccessRule ar
    JOIN AccessRule.RuleOperation ro ON ar.AccessRuleId = ro.AccessRuleId
    JOIN AccessRule.RuleField rf ON ro.FieldId = rf.RuleFieldId
    ) AS t
pivot(max([value]) FOR [FieldName] IN (
            [BusinessArea]
            ,[ProviderTaxId]
            ,[VendorName]
            )) AS pt
```

[image]

Comment: Sample data, and expected results, *not* images, will help us help you.

Comment: You do have an aggregate. Why not add `accessruleId` to the group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to merge the value for the field before the pivoting:

```
;WITH cte_raw(AccessRuleId,EffectiveDate,TermDate,CreatedByUser,LastUpdatedUser,FieldName,Value)
AS
(
    SELECT ar.AccessRuleId
        ,ar.EffectiveDate
        ,ar.TermDate
        ,ar.CreatedByUser
        ,ar.LastUpdatedUser
        ,rf.FieldName
        ,ro.Value
    FROM AccessRule.AccessRule ar
    JOIN AccessRule.RuleOperation ro ON ar.AccessRuleId = ro.AccessRuleId
    JOIN AccessRule.RuleField rf ON ro.FieldId = rf.RuleFieldId
),
cte_merged(AccessRuleId,EffectiveDate,TermDate,CreatedByUser,LastUpdatedUser,FieldName,Value)
AS
(
  SELECT r.AccessRuleId,r.EffectiveDate,r.TermDate,r.CreatedByUser,r.LastUpdatedUser,r.FieldName,
    STUFF((SELECT N','+v.Value
        FROM cte_raw v
        WHERE v.AccessRuleId=r.AccessRuleId
        AND v.EffectiveDate=r.EffectiveDate
        AND v.TermDate=r.TermDate
        AND v.CreatedByUser=r.CreatedByUser
        AND v.LastUpdatedUser=r.LastUpdatedUser
        AND v.FieldName=r.FieldName
        ORDER BY v.Value
        FROM XML PATH (N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(4000)')
      ,1,1,N'') AS Value
  FROM cte_raw r
  GROUP BY r.AccessRuleId
      ,r.EffectiveDate
      ,r.TermDate
      ,r.CreatedByUser
      ,r.LastUpdatedUser
      ,r.FieldName
)
SELECT *
FROM cte_merged t
pivot(max([value]) FOR [FieldName] IN (
      [BusinessArea]
      ,[ProviderTaxId]
      ,[VendorName]
      )) AS pt
```

Comment: I had to change FROM XML to FOR XML, but this works.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this in an a more simplified way.

```
SELECT ar.AccessRuleId
            ,ar.EffectiveDate
            ,ar.TermDate
            ,(select Value from AccessRule.RuleOperation ro where ro.AccessRuleId = ar.AccessRuleId and ro.FieldId = 2) as ProviderTaxId
            ,(select Value from AccessRule.RuleOperation ro where ro.AccessRuleId = ar.AccessRuleId and ro.FieldId = 3) as VendorName
            ,(SELECT STUFF( (SELECT ',' + value FROM AccessRule.RuleOperation ro where ro.AccessRuleId = ar.AccessRuleId  and ro.FieldId = 1 FOR XML PATH('')),1, 1, '')) AS BusinessAreas
        FROM AccessRule.AccessRule ar
```